# Laravel: Remove a video from a playlist in YouTube using Google API Client

Tags: php, laravel, youtube, youtube-api, google-client

Hi so I am trying to remove videos from a playlist using the google api client, so far I keep getting wrong parameter errors. here is my code right now.

```
    if($access_token && $client = \GoogleClient::requestPermission($access_token)) {

        $youtube = new \Google_Service_YouTube($client);

        $resultMain = $youtube->playlistItems->delete("id,snippet", array('id' => $video_id, 'playlistId' => $playlist_id));

    }else{

        App::abort(500,"Cannot authenticate account");
    }
```

what am i doing wrong and any help is appreciated. thanks!